# how to write a servlet connected with jsp for login page

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want to connect my jsp login page with servlet to authenticate username and password.

My login page is login.jsp:

```
<html>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="name">Please Enter you username
    <input type="password" name="password id="pass">Please Enter you password
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Login page form must have a form action having a path to your servlet like given below.

```
<form action="Servlet_Name_With_Path">
```

Answer (score 0):

Very roughly:

```
public class AuthenticationService{
    public boolean authenticate(Strign userName, String password){
        //plug in to some 'proper' authentication logic here
        return userName.equals("Alia") && password.equals("password");
    }
}

public class AuthenticationServlet extends HttpServlet{

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttPServletResponse response){
        AuthenticationService service = new AuthenticationService();
        String userName = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        if(service.authenticate(userName, password)){
            request.getRequestDispatcher("success.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }else{
            request.getRequestDispatcher("error.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your **login.jsp** should be as follows

```
<html>
<form action=login method=post>
<input type="text" name="username" id="name">Please Enter you username
<input type="password" name="password id="pass">Please Enter you password
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

your **web.xml** should be as follows

```
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>packagename.class name</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    <servlet-mapping>
```

Say for example your Servlet Class name is LoginServlet and it is package com.test. Then it should be as `<servlet-class>com.test.LoginServlet</servlet-class>`. And the Servlet code must be as explained above by @Alan Hay